# How not to use CompletableFuture as a shared state with EventListener in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I need to asynchronously react to the `@EventListener`, therefore I've created something like this.

```
@Service
public class AsyncHandler {

    private CompletableFuture<My> future;

    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<My> getMy() {
        future = new CompletableFuture<>();
        return future;
    }

    @EventListener
    public void processEvent(MyEvent event) {
        future.complete(event.my());
    }
}
```

The problem here is that `AsyncHandler` is now stateful. Which is wrong.
And I don't want to use database, so is there any other way to make the bean stateless while using `@EventListener`?

Comment: From this question and little info I have no idea whatyou are trying to achieve. Why not just make the `@EventListener` method `@Async`. This feels like a very convoluted way to achieve this.

Comment: Well, there is suppose to be a client waiting for an event and some async process initialized somewhere else to do something and notify client after it has been finished.
Like for example internet banking using website, when you set a new payment and than you must confirm it on your smartphone in application. Website IB waits for confirmation on smartphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, your singleton has state, which is "not good".

One (possible) solution:

1. make the/refactor "statfeul part" to a "prototype" (request, session) scope bean.
2. make your "singleton" abstract!
3. inject the "stateful part" via "method injection" (we cannot "auto wire" lower(shorter-living) scope beans to higher ones...)

As code (example):

1. State holder:

   ```
   public class MyStateHolder {
      // State:
      private CompletableFuture<My> future;

      @Async // ?
      public CompletableFuture<My> getMy() {
        future = new CompletableFuture<>();
        return future;
      }
   }
   ```
2. Abstract, (no `@Service` ..yet, no state!):

   ```
   public abstract class AsyncHandler {
     @EventListener
     public void processEvent(MyEvent event) { 
        // !!
        delegate().getMy().complete(event.my());
     }

     // and now only (abstract!):
     public abstract MyStateHolder delegate();
   }
   ```
3. Wiring :

   ```
   @Configuration
   class MyConfig {

     @Bean
     @Scope("prototype") // !
     public MyStateHolder stateful() {
       return new MyStateHolder();
     }

     @Bean // singleton/service:
     public AsyncHandler asyncHandler() {
       return new AsyncHandler() { // !
         @Override // !
         public MyStateHolder delegate() {
           return stateful();// !;)
         }
       };
     }
   }
   ```

refs: (most of) https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html

Especially:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-sing-prot-interaction

Comment: This is nice and clean solution. Thank you.

Comment: thank you, but i am also confused by the "async part" (i just ref*ctored:) .. see: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/EventListener.html (-> "Asynchronous Listeners")